# How to position/align a button using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning web design and I'm struggling to position a button. I'm a beginner and trying to recreate league of legends client which is pretty simple in browser just for exercise, but I don't know how to use javascript and I can not find the solution online.

So this is how I want it to look: https://prnt.sc/pos3gf

I've tried to add logo and button in list and then `display: inline` but that doesn't really work or I just don't know to make it work.

This is my code

https://codepen.io/simic21/pen/poowQXK

Comment: You can copy/paste the relevant parts of the code here. Images are not a problem.

Comment: what about adding 
.centered {
  display:flex;
}
It will make those 2 items on the left stay next to each other in a row. Is this the result you're looking for ?

Comment: @AdamKniec this worked, thank you a lot. https://prnt.sc/pp9qia I will allign it better now, the hard part was moving it there

Answer (score 0):

I removed all of the CSS before `/*====== REGION ======*//* Dropdown Button */` and replaced it with this:

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.region {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

That will display the logo and region divs side by side. Now the only thing left is to add the rest of your desired styling such as padding or margin.

Comment: It doesn't really show me the same result, the CSS before region is for splitting the page so right div is only picture and left is content. Heres how my site looks after i deleted everything before region and added your css https://prnt.sc/poskk2

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `.region` class `display:inline-block` and the same to your `.logo` class:

```css
.region {
  padding: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.logo {
  padding: 40px 0px 0px 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="region">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">   
      <strong>EUNE(EN)</strong></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did exactly that. Maybe you did not understand me? I want them to be like in the picture, one right from another, but when i implement this its just under like before?